# Modifying the page from a google maps marker click event

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to modify page a Google Map is embedded in when the user clicks on a marker (resize the map and display info about the marker). I thought I could just do something like this as an example for the resizing of the map:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
    map.setZoom(8);
    map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
    $('#MapContainer').switchClass("MapContainer", "MapContainerSmall");
    $('#MapCanvas').switchClass("MapCanvas", "MapCanvasSmall");
    google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize')
});
```

But the jQuery does not execute / change the class. I am assuming this is because I cannot place jQuery code within the Google maps API events?

I realize there must be lack of understanding on my part in what I am able to do here - can someone push me in the right direction?

EDIT:

Fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/43XbM/

Comment: Any javascript errors?  Can you provide enough code that we can replicate the problem (and maybe a fiddle that demonstrates the issue)?

Comment: @geocodezip Edited to include this.

Comment: switchClass is not part of jQuery, it is part of [jQueryUI](http://api.jqueryui.com/switchclass/), you need to [include that in the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/43XbM/3/) (and perhaps your environment, if you are seeing the same error there).

Comment: Here is a version of [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/43XbM/5/) that works for me.  Waits until the div has finished resizing before running setCenter/setZoom and triggering the resize event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wait for the div switch to be complete (the "complete" option in the switchClass function) before triggering the resize event and setting the new center and zoom.

```
var map;
var site1 = new google.maps.LatLng(67.62, -134.13);


    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(64, -117);
    var settings = {
        zoom: 4,
        maxZoom: 10,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeControl: true,
        mapTypeControlOptions: { style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU },
        navigationControl: true,
        navigationControlOptions: { style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL },
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("MapCanvas"), settings);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: site1,
        map: map,
        title: "Hello World!"
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {

        $('#MapContainer').switchClass("MapContainer", "MapContainerSmall");
        $('#MapCanvas').switchClass("MapCanvas", "MapCanvasSmall", null, null,
          function() {
          google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize')
          map.setZoom(8);
          map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
        });

    });
```

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/43XbM/5/)